# Como ejecutar un composer update dentro de la carpeta de mi proyecto

Tags: php, composer, actualizacion

Necesito actualizar el composer dentro de la carpeta de mi proyecto con **php**, pero sucede que he hecho una larga búsqueda en YouTube y en Google y no encuentro ninguna información que me pueda ayudar.

Tengo un error varios errores en mi proyecto que se pueden solucionar actualizando el composer del proyecto.
Si alguien me puede dar algún tipo de información de como actualizo el composer de mi proyecto, se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Si necesitan mas información, solo háganlo saber. Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Con este comando `php composer.phar update`

Comment: Lo siento amigo, pero no me ha funcionado, estoy tratando de actualizar el composer de un proyecto desarrollado en Symfony y angular, el proyecto fue desarrollado a comienzo de 2016, el composer esta muy antiguo y el proyecto me esta dando problemas por esa razón

Comment: No funciona el comando? Te salió algún error?

Comment: Me funciono usando el comando `composer update`